# Android WebView restoreState freeze

Tags: android, webview

My question is related to many existing questions concerning handling WebView after orientation change.

I know that the activity is than destroyed, so I use onSaveInstanceState() to save its state and later I restore it with restoreState().

And this works fine most of the time. But it doesn't when I change the orientation too quickly - immediately after starting my activity or creating WebView object after return from different layout. Debugging shows that my WebView state gets saved (and that all the objects are already created and prepared when the orientation change occurs) and it tries to restore the state but somehow it cannot. There are no errors of any kind but the page is never loaded, I see infinite white screen. Calling WebView.reload() also doesn't help.

Any idea why this happens? As I said, all the object are created at the time of orientation change and loadUrl() method was called, so the state should be saved correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your WebView Bundle. If it is EMPTY then don't restore state.

```
if (!bundleObject.isEmpty()) {
    mWebView.restoreState(bundleObject);
```

}

Comment: Yes, that is a correct answer! I only checked if (bundleObject != null) and it was not enough. The isEmpty() function does the trick.

Alternatively I just found out that you can do:
WebBackForwardList retval = myWebView.restoreState(bundleObject); and check if the retval is not null.